# Force children to use enums defined within themselves

Tags: java, generics, enums, enumset

Let's say I've got a parent abstract animal trainer class:

```
public abstract class Trainer 
  <A extends Animal, 
   E extends Enum<E> & Trainables>{
    protected EnumSet<E> completed;
    public void trainingComplete(E trainable){
      trainingComplete.add(trainable);
    }
```

I want concrete extensions of the parent animal trainer to complete training for only the trainables defined by it. So if I have a concrete Dog Trainer as follows:

```
public class DogTrainer extends Trainer<Dog, DogTrainer.Tricks>{
  public enum Tricks implements Trainables {
    FETCH, GROWL, SIT, HEEL;
  }
}
```

With the current definition of `DogTrainer` I can only do `trainingComplete` for parameters of the `DogTrainer.Tricks` type. But I want to enforce that anyone who creates a concrete `Trainer` should allow `trainingComplete()` for `Trainables` that it defines within itself.

In other words, the problem with my current design is, if I had another trainer as follows:

```
public class PoliceDogTrainer extends Trainer<Dog, PoliceDogTrainer.Tricks>{
  public enum Tricks implements Trainables {
     FIND_DRUGS, FIND_BOMB, FIND_BODY;
  }
}
```

There is nothing preventing someone from defining another rouge trainer that tries to teach the dog, police tricks:

```
public class RougeTrainer extends Trainer<Dog, PoliceDogTrainer.Tricks>{
 ...
}
```

I want to prohibit this and allow extending class to use ONLY Trainables they themselves specify.

How can I do that?

Comment: I think this is also solved by the solution for my :
[earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19435006/force-children-to-use-enums-defined-within-themselves).

Answer (score 1):

You can make the `enum`s non-`public` but that cannot be enforced by the abstract base class. An alternative is to make `Trainables` generic by adding a type parameter which must match the `Trainer` class. This does not enforce the `enum` to be an inner class (that’s impossible) but for a conforming sub class, no `RogueTrainer` can be created then.

Enforcing constraints on the type of `this` inside the base class or interface lies somewhere between tricky and impossible. One commonly known example is the `Comparable` interface which cannot be declared in a way to prevent implementations like `class Foo implements Comparable<String>`.

One way to circumvent this problem is to make the `Trainer` reference a parameter, e.g.

```
public interface Trainables<T extends Trainer<?,? extends Trainables<T>>>
…
public abstract class Trainer 
  <A extends Animal,
   E extends Enum<E> & Trainables<? extends Trainer<A,E>>> {

  protected EnumSet<E> completed;

  void trainingCompleteImpl(E trainable) {
    completed.add(trainable);
  }

  public static <A extends Animal, T extends Trainer<A,E>,
    E extends Enum<E> & Trainables<T>> void trainingComplete(T t, E trainable) {
    t.trainingCompleteImpl(trainable);
  }
}

public class PoliceDogTrainer
  extends Trainer<Dog, PoliceDogTrainer.Tricks> {

  public enum Tricks implements Trainables<PoliceDogTrainer> {
     FIND_DRUGS, FIND_BOMB, FIND_BODY;
  }
}
```

The `public static` method can only be invoked with the right combination of `Trainer` and `Trainables`. The `trainingCompleteImpl` method can be invoked and overridden by trusted subclasses within the same package. If you don’t want this you can inline the code of the method and remove the instance method completely.

_

An alternative is to create a type parameter for the `Trainer` and enforce a match between the parameter and `this` at runtime:

```
public interface Trainables<T extends Trainer<?,T,? extends Trainables<T>>>
…
public abstract class Trainer 
  <A extends Animal, T extends Trainer<A,T,E>,
   E extends Enum<E> & Trainables<T>> {

  protected EnumSet<E> completed;

  /** sub-classes should implements this as {@code return this}*/
  protected abstract T selfReference();

  void trainingComplete(E trainable) {
    if(selfReference()!=this) throw new IllegalStateException();
    completed.add(trainable);
  }
}
public class PoliceDogTrainer
  extends Trainer<Dog, PoliceDogTrainer, PoliceDogTrainer.Tricks> {

  public enum Tricks implements Trainables<PoliceDogTrainer> {
     FIND_DRUGS, FIND_BOMB, FIND_BODY;
  }

  @Override
  protected final PoliceDogTrainer selfReference()
  {
    return this;
  }
}
```

So, for a non-conforming `Trainer` implementation `selfReference()` cannot be implemented as `return this;` which can be detected easily. For a conforming implementation the JVM will inline the `selfReference` method and see `this==this` then which will be optimized away; so this check has no performance impact.

Comment: So `Trainables` should be defined as `public interface Trainables<T extends Trainer>`? How can I enforce that in the parent `Trainer`

Comment: I extended the answer